# iOS pass data when using storyboard to push the view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, pushviewcontroller

I am starting to use storyboard more often but I have run into a problem. Usually when you push a view controller using a UINavigationController you do it in the following way and you are able to pass data along with it:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.link = [self link];
vc.name = [self name];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc]
[nav presentViewController:vc completion:nil animated:YES];
```

(I did the above code for memory so it may not be 100% correct).

Now that I am using storyboard, I am not instantiating the view controllers myself so how do I pass data with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

For example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueID"])
    {
        UIViewController * vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.link = [self link];
        vc.name = [self name];
    }
}
```

Or, if your destination view controller is a `UINavigationController`, use this:

```
UINavigationController * navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
UIViewController * vc = [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem right now, but I don't know how to find the segue identifier.

My ViewController is brought up after calling

    `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`

I didn't make a segue in the storyboard, so I don't know what to use for the identifier to send the data with.

Comment: Oops, forgot to tag you, @StephSharp

Comment: @Inbl If you're pushing a view onto a navigation controller and not using segues, you don't need `prepareForSegue:sender:`. Just set up the data for `vc` before pushing it onto the navigation controller (similar to the code in the question).

Comment: @StephSharp I've tried this, but all properties seem to be null.

Comment: @Inbl It would probably be best for you to ask a new question and include your code. It seems like your issue is different to this one, and it would make it easier to work out what's going wrong if I could see your code.